# How to pass a function that handles properties to a container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following parent class

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<IParentComponentProps, any> {
  constructor(props: IParentComponent Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shouldResetFocus: false,
    };
  }

public render() {
   return (
      <BodyComponent shouldResetFocus={this.state.shouldResetFocus} />
      <FooterContainer />
   );
}
```

}

This is the BodyComponent class

```
    
    export interface BodyComponentProps {
      shouldResetFocus: boolean;
    }
    
    class BodyComponent extends React.Component<IBodyComponentProps>{ 
        private containerRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IBodyComponentProps) {
          if (this.props.shouldResetFocus && !prevProps.shouldResetFocus) {
           const nextFocusableElement = this.containerRef?.current;
           if (nextFocusableElement) {
             nextFocusableElement.focus();
           }
         }
        }

        render () { 
         let body = //bunch of body logic
         return (
           <div tabIndex={0} ref={this.containerRef}>
            {<BackButtonContainer />}
            {body}
          </div>
        );
   }
```

The thing is that the FooterContainer class is a container component class that has the FooterComponent class and it uses the connect method. In this class I have a button that needs to change the shouldResetFocus property from BodyComponent to true or false. How do I pass down the function to handle the property into the container? And how do I match them to be able to communicate with his sibling component?

This is the FooterContainer class

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState, _ownProps: any) => {
 return {
  // mappings
 };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  // mappings
};

export const FooterContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(styled(FooterComponent, getStyles));
```

This is the FooterComponent class

```
export class FooterComponent extends React.Component<IFooterComponentProps> {
   render () {
     <button onClick={this.onBtnClick()} />
   }

   onBtnClick = () => {
     //other logic

     //here I need to trigger the method the would change the shouldResetFocus to true
     // something like this.props.handleReset(true)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> here I need to trigger the method the would change the shouldResetFocus to true
> something like this.props.handleReset(true)

Simply create a function that sets the state to true like this:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<IParentComponentProps, any> {
  constructor(props: IParentComponent Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shouldResetFocus: false,
    };

    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

handleReset(reset: boolean) {
   this.setState({
      shouldResetFocus: true;
   })
}

public render() {
   return (
      <BodyComponent shouldResetFocus={this.state.shouldResetFocus} />
      <FooterContainer handleReset={this.handleReset}/>
   );
}
```

And in the footer component:

```
interface IFooterComponentProps {
   handleReset: (reset: boolean) => void;
}

export class FooterComponent extends React.Component<IFooterComponentProps> {
   render () {
     <button onClick={this.onBtnClick()} />
   }

   onBtnClick = () => {
     this.props.handleReset(true)
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it common and a good practice to pass a function binding like handleReset={this.handleReset} through a container?

Comment: I think so, in their documentation they even have a `mapStateToProps` function so you handle component's `ownProps` and redux state at the same time, see it more [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md). You could also put `shouldResetFocus` on redux state, then you wouldn't have to pass a function as props

Comment: How would you approach it with redux state. I was trying to do that but it requires to create more clases